# EKEvent accept invitation

Tags: ios, objective-c, eventkit, ekevent

How do you accept an `EKEvent` invitation in iOS? I know it's possible as *Fantastical*, *Calendars 5*, and other calendar apps have this functionality, but I don't see an exposed non read-only property to change the user's status in regards to an event.
Any idea how to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: This should help you. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKitUI/Reference/EKEventViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, after doing some more research, that all of these apps are just displaying the `EKEventViewController`. What I had mistaken as customization was actually view tints.

Comment: TimePage is not using EKEventUI layout, how does it performs the accept/decline?

Comment: Hi Kyle! Using EKEventViewController doesn't work for me. The layout appears but the buttons (accept/maybe/decline) don't perform any action in the calendar. How did you manage? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170415/how-to-accept-decline-ekevent-invitation