# Accepting/Declining EKEvent invitation

Tags: ios, eventkit

So I'm trying to figure out how to programmatically accept or deny a meeting invite for an `EKEvent` object in Swift. So far I've tried to change the status, but it's a read only action. For the time being, I show the `EKEventViewController()` but it doesn't allow me to programmatically do it.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: FYI - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170415/how-to-accept-decline-ekevent-invitation and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24368096/ekevent-accept-invitation (you are not alone trying to find an answer).

Comment: I know :/ I thought maybe somebody has come up with a solution. Still nothing I guess, confused because Timepage and a few calendar apps found a solution to this